# What is the time complexity of the given code

Tags: time-complexity

I want to know the time complexity of the code attached.
I get O(n^2logn), while my friends get O(nlogn) and O(n^2).

SomeMethod() = log n
Here is the code:

```
j = i**2;
for (k = 0; k < j; k++) {
    for (p = 0; p < j; p++) {
        x += p;
    }
    someMethod();
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the N in your code?  Is it `i` ?  Is it `j`?

Comment: o sorry we just use n for everything because this is grade 12 so assume everything is in n

Comment: My answer is either `O(N^2)` or `O(N^4)` depending on the answer to the previous question.

Comment: That response doesn't make sense.  You cannot do a complexitiy anaylsis unless you say what the variable is.

Comment: @StephenC Look at the picture I posted of the question

Comment: Also 1) you have changed the question, and 2) there must be a hidden variable for `someMethod()` to be anything other than `O(1)`.  This question is nonsensical from a math perspective and has no answer.

Comment: @WajdanFaheem are there any options?

Comment: @StephenC by the way, it doesn't have to be in terms of `n` . The time complexity could also be expressed in terms of `i` and `j`

Comment: @ArunGowda okay assume that i and j are both n

Comment: @ArunGowda - the picture shows two independent variables: `i` and `N`.  If we take this literally the complexity class has two variables.  If not, *we don't know what the question means*.

Comment: @WajdanFaheem - That doesn't make sense. `i` and `j` are different variables.  They can't *both* be `N`.

Comment: I removed some irrelevant tags.  This is not [java] and nothing to do with either [time] or [eclipse]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not very clear about the variable `N` and the statement `i**2`.

`i**2` gives a compilation error in java.

assuming `someMethod()` takes `log N` time(as mentioned in question), and  completely ignoring value of `N`,

lets call `i**2` as `Z`

`someMethod();` runs `Z` times. and time complexity of the method is `log N` so that becomes:

`Z * log N` ----------------------------------------- A

lets call this expression A.

Now, `x+=p` runs Z^2 times (`i` loop * `j` loop) and takes constant time to run. that makes the following expression:

`( Z^2 ) * 1 = ( Z^2 )`  ---------------------- B

lets call this expression B.

The total run time is sum of expression `A` and expression `B`. which brings us to:

`O((Z * log N) + (Z^2))`

where `Z = i**2`

so final expression will be `O(((i**2) * log N) + ((i**2)^2))`

if we can assume `i**2` is `i^2`, the expression becomes,

`O(((i^2) * log N) + (i^4))`

Considering only the higher order variables, like we consider `n^2` in `n^2 + 2n + 5`, the complexity can be expressed as follows,

`i^4`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the picture, the complexity is O(logNI<sup>2</sup> + I<sup>4</sup>).

We cannot give a complexity class with one variable because the picture does not explain the relationship between `N` and `I`.  They must be treated as separate variables.

And likewise, we cannot eliminate the logNI<sup>2</sup> term because the `N` variable will dominate the `I` variable in some regions of `N x I` space.

---

If we treat `N` as a constant, then the complexity class reduces to  O(I<sup>4</sup>).

We get the same if we treat `N` as being the same thing as `I`; i.e. there is a typo in the question.

---

(I think there is mistake in the way the question was set / phrased.  If not, this is a *trick question* designed to see if you really understood the mathematical principles behind complexity involving multiple independent variables.)